# Sum of all entries In a Matrix of Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

So,few days before I had a Linear Algebra Test and we had following question :

Let $P_3[R]$ denote the vector space of all polynomials with degree $\le 3$. Define the linear Transformation $P_3[R]$ $\to$ $P_3[R]$ defined by :

$T(p(x))$ = $p(x)$ + $p'(x)$ + $p''(x)$ Then find the sum of all the matrix of T relative to the usual basis.

Now the basis for given vector space is :$\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ , Using this:

$T(1)$ =  $1$

$T(x)$ = $x$ + $1$ +$0$ = $1.1$ + $1.x$ + $0.x^2$ + $0.x^3$

$T(x^2$) = $x^2$ +  $2x$ + $2$  = $2.1$ + $2.x$ + $1.x^2$  + $0.x^3$

$T(x^3)$ = $x^3$ + $3x^2$ + $6x$ =  $0.1$ + $6.x$ + $3.x^2$ +  $1.x^3$

The Matrix is given by  :

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 2 & 6 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 3\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Clearly sum of all entries in the matrix is $18$ but the answer given to me is $24$

Can anyone tell me what is the error in my solution ?

Thank you.

Comment: You made  mistake in typing the first column but the answer is $18$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking if your result is the good one is facilitated by the decomposition of $T$ into the sum of three operators : identity, derivation, derivation of order two :

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}+
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 3\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}+
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 6 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 2 & 6\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 3\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

(see in particular how the diagonals are moving upwards).

This shows your result is good (entries' summation gives $18$).

It would have been $24$ if the operator had been with a supplementary term $p'''(x)$, bringing a $6$ in the upper right entry of the above matrix.

Answer (score 1):

In $$(1+x+x^2+x^3)+(1+2x+3x^2)+(2+6x),$$

the sum of the coefficients is $18$.

In $$(1+x+x^2+x^3)+(1+2x+3x^2)+(2+6x)+(6),$$

it is $24$.

Comment: so $18$ is the correct answer ?

Comment: In other words: the book answer would be correct if the linear transformation were $T(p(x))=p(x)+p’(x)+p’’(x)+p’’’(x)$.

Comment: @zeroflank: so somebody made a mistake.